# Bind to a structure property in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, data-binding

I am trying to bind structure members to `Label`s in [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms). However, I'm unable to do this because this structure is a member of a class, and I need to bind a couple of members to Labels.

Let's say that this structure is a `System.Drawing.Point`, and I want to bind `X` and `Y` property to a `Label`.

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel
Public Class Form1
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private _pt As Point
    Public Property Pt As Point
        Get
            Return _pt
        End Get
        Set(value As Point)
            _pt = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("Pt"))
        End Set
    End Property


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", Me, "Pt")
        Label2.DataBindings.Add("Text", Me.Pt, "X")
        Label3.DataBindings.Add("Text", Me, "Pt.Y")
    End Sub

    Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

End Class
```

If I set the `bindingsource` to `Me` and `datamember` to structure then `Label1` will show the result of `ToString()` method, `Label2` value of `X` property and `Label3` will not change.

But if I assign a new `Point` to `Pt` property, then only `Label1` will update its value. `Label2` will not because `datasource` is no longer the same. Also, `Label3.DataBindings.Add("Text", Me, "Pt.Y")` does not work, because it's not possible that `datamember` is "submember".

I have also tried to make a new Structure that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` in all its properties, but no luck.

Is there a way to make binding for `Label2` or `Label3` possible, even if I assign new Structure to it?

My goal is to assign new `Point` to `Me.Pt` property and observe values of `Pt.X` and `Pt.Y` on `Label2` and `Label3` via databinding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it right. `Label1` and `Label3` will work AS IS. Change

```
Label2.DataBindings.Add("Text", Me.Pt, "X")
```

to

```
Label2.DataBindings.Add("Text", Me, "Pt.X")
```

And `Label2` will also start working.

Just make sure you assign a new value through a property, and not through your `_pt` field.

Comment: Assigning through a property Pt.X or Pt.Y is not what I had in mind, because this is just simple example, in real life I have a structure with 10 properties, and make assignment Me.Pt = another Stucture every 0.5 sec, so this nullifies a idea of Structure as a container for 10 Doubles

Comment: @VinkoSurija: Perhaps I did not make myself clear enough. Assign through a property means any change to Pt, including `Pt = New Point(...)`, or `Pt = New MyClass(...)`. As long as PropertyChanged is raised, I see no reason why it would not work.

Comment: `DataBindings.Add("Text", Me, "Pt.X")` raises an `ArgumentException`: "Cannot bind to the property or column X on the DataSource."

Comment: @VinkoSurija: What's your framework version and IDE? It works fine for me (VS 2010 + .NET 4.0).

Comment: VS2010 + .Net 4.0. This exception does not halt debugger but is visible if you break program and look into IntelliTrace. My labels still show text assigned in Designer

Comment: @VinkoSurija: I recorded [a video illustrating how everything works for me](http://www.mediafire.com/?hi6qertf5magro5). You may record yours to show where it gets an exception.

Comment: I have also recorded [a video illustrating how exception raises](http://www.4shared.com/rar/8XwehRIa/2013-01-29_1021.html). How much I can see, everything looks the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding properties `Pt_X` and `Pt_Y` to your form, with `Get` methods that simply return the values of `_pt.X` and `_pt.Y`.  In addition, you should have your `Pt` property setter check whether `_pt.X` or `_pt.Y` is going to be changed and raise the appropriate events if so.

Alternatively, you could define a class which will act as an interface between the `Point` class and the labels.  Any changes to `pt` would notify this class, which would then compute what should go in the label and relay that to the label in question.

Comment: I have thought of this first idea, but it seamed not in a true spirit of databinding

Comment: @VinkoSurija: Live data-binding only works usefully with mutable objects whose identity is immutable and persistable; if an object is data bound and someone changes one of its properties, the property setter can know that it's the same object that was data-bound.  Structures generally have no such identity.  If one could somehow data-bind to a `Point` which had x=4 y=3, and some `Point` which had x=4 and y=3 was changed to have x=5, there would be no reasonable way of knowing whether it was the *same* struct that had been data-bound, or was a different struct that happened to hold x=4 y=3.

Comment: @VinkoSurija: Despite such limitations, however, mutable structs make certain forms of change-tracking easier. If an class `Foo` has a field `Pt` of a struct type like `Point`, any change to the fields of `Pt` must go through `Foo`, which means `Foo` will know about them even without data-binding. If `Pt` had been a mutable class type and `Foo` ever exposed a reference to it, then even if `Pt` supported data binding or update notifications, `Foo` would have to go through a lot of work to know when it changed; if `Pt` didn't support data binding, `Foo` might not be able to know when it changed.